# define php what wrong in my code

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

```
define("EW_ENCODING", "utf-8", TRUE); 
$encode = EW_ENCODING ;
mysql_set_charset(EW_ENCODING,$con);
$charset = mysql_client_encoding($con);

echo "The current character set is: $charset\n";
```

Why doesn't this code print `utf-8`? When I run this code it actually prints

```
The current character set is: latin1
```

How can I get the desired result?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQL uses non-standard character set names.  Try `utf8` without the dash.

Comment: I so hate MySQL for that, screws with my head every time. >_<

Answer (score 3):

Try calling

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8;");
```

too.

Comment: EW_ENCODING this one is stay on configuration file so i need to use it so when i change something i will change on one place

Comment: `mysql_set_charset` should be enough.